# Need help understanding how to define both static and instantiatable classes in javascript

Tags: javascript

current broken code: http://jsfiddle.net/9F52n/2/

What I'm trying to do: Learn how to define an object/function that behaves like a class, and be able to define subclasses, both static , and instantiatable (singleton in my example below).

Currently, my code below doesn't work all that well. but, if the instantiatable class sand the static class were removed, you'll see that I have the very basics of class creation down.

So, I guess my question is: what is the proper / most semantic way to define nested clases (singleton or otherwise) with the way I've defined TBR? `(function(){...})(window)`

```
var TBR = (function() {
    // define local copy of taco bell run
    var TBR = function() {
        return new TBR.fn.init();
    },
        message = "hello world!";

    TBR.fn = TBR.prototype = {
        constructor: TBR,
        init: function() {
            console.log("From TBR Constructor: " + message);
        }
    }

    var InstantiatableClass = function() {
        return new TBR.InstantiatableClass, fn.init();
    }

   InstantiatableClass.fn =InstantiatableClass.prototype = {
        constructor: TBR.InstantiatableClass,
        init: function() {
            console.log("from InstantiatableClass: " + message);
        }
    }

    this.staticClass = function() {
        var subMessage = "little world";
        init = function() {
            console.log("from staticClass: " + subMessage);
        }
    }
    // expose TBR to the window object
    window.TBR = TBR;

})(window);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "static class"?

Comment: just a class that doesn't need instantiation

Comment: the way I have TBR is kinda like that? idk, I modeled it after jQuery, where it init's itself

Comment: Uh, you should not use jQuery's "class" model, it's quirks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var InstantiatableClass = function() {
    return new TBR.InstantiatableClass, fn.init();
}

InstantiatableClass.fn =InstantiatableClass.prototype ...
```

This does not work. Your `InstantiatableClass` local variable returns objects, the prototype will not get applied to them. Also, `TBR.InstantiatableClass` is defined nowhere. If that is what you wanted, you'd need to use

```
function InstantiatableClass() {
    // common constructor things
}
TBR.InstantiatableClass = InstantiatableClass; // assign a "static" property
```

Also, you should not [need to] overwrite the prototypes. Sure, the only difference is that `constructor` is enumerable now (as far as it is not forgotten), but the following would be much cleaner:

```
InstantiatableClass.fn = InstantiatableClass.prototype; // shortcut
InstantiatableClass.fn.init = function() { … };
```

---

Oh, you want something that works like jQuery. Imho you should not make the constructor (`init`) a property of the prototype - that is just very odd and I can't see a reason to do so. I'd suggest this code:

```
window.TBR = (function() {
    function TbrConstructor() {
        …
    }
    function InstantiableConstructor() {
        …
    }

    // Now, the creator functions:
    function TBR() { return new TbrConstructor; }
    function Instantiable() { return new InstantiableConstructor; }

    // Now, overwrite the "prototype" properties - this is needed for
    // (new TbrConstructor) instanceof TBR === true
    // and also create those fn shortcuts
    TBR.fn = TBR.prototype = TbrConstructor.prototype;
    Instantiable.fn = Instantiable.prototype = InstantiableConstructor.prototype;

    // we might overwrite the "constructor" properties like
    TBR.fn.constructor = TBR;
    // but I don't see much sense in that - they also have no semantic value

    // At last, make Instantiable a property on the TBR function object:
    TBR.Instantiable = Instantiable;
    // and then only
    return TBR;
})();

// Usage

TBR(); // returns a TbrConstructor instance
TBR.Instantiable(); // returns a InstantiableConstructor instance
```

Comment: I've applied your suggestions here, but TBR still doesn't have `InstantiatableClass` http://jsfiddle.net/9F52n/5/ did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, it would be `window.TBR.InstantiatableClass();` - the "subclass" is not a property of `TBR` instances.

Comment: Cool, I see how this works, thanks for adding all the comments! =D
But now, how would I add methods to each of the "subclasses"? I feel this approach kinda strays from the semantics that I was trying with my original code. =(

Comment: Just as to any other functions: either as privileged ones in the constructor, or on the prototype.

Comment: ok, so, I'm trying to do what your saying, and also trying to organize everything so responsibility of code is within the "class" it belongs to: http://jsfiddle.net/9F52n/20/  But, I'm getting that the iClass (new name for instantiable, caues instantiable is too long / hard to spell correctly repeatedly) is getting instantiated twice, instead of TBR once, and iClass once. When I run TBR(), it also instantiates iClass. Why is that?

Comment: to the last question: because you overwrite `init`. I'm afraid there were so many errors I had to comment them [in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9F52n/22/) (the /**/ comments)

Comment: I guess "self" is supposed to be a singleton reference, is it? If so, I would say you are doing too much stuff - a singleton object never does need a prototype, for example. Have you tried a simple object literal instead?

Comment: I have, just doing TBR.whatever = {} and TBR.whatever. something = {} works fine. Just exploring different ways of doing things =D thanks for all your help. I need to do some more reading I guess.

Comment: Umm, the TBR function in that fiddle just returns itself. Are you sure that is what you wanted?

Comment: Hmm, maybe not, cause I still don't have access to TBR().constant. I suppose I could just not worry about a constructor, and do TBR the way I did Sub. =\